# What do I share when I connect to a public wireless network

Tags: wireless, privacy, ip-address

Is there a list of data/infos Ubuntu (or other Linux distributions) share when connecting to a (public) wireless network?
Such as mac address, hostname, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on type of network. I assume here a usual LAN, where each device is able to ping each another, as it shares the most information.

1. MAC address. You *must* share it to be able to use DHCP. At the very moment you're connected to a network with DHCP, the system should send DHCPDISCOVERY, which is an ask to assign an IP to given MAC address. This message is broadcast, so every computer on the network would see it.

   You can actually configure the system to not use DHCP, and assign a IP statically. Then MAC address might leak upon ARP name resolution in between physically connected devices too. Note that you almost always can fake your MAC *(excluding when your network card doesn't support it, which is utterly rare)*.
2. IP address. Upon any network activity, like using a browser or playing games, your browser sends TCP or UDP packets to a gateway, and this traffic is publicily seen, and could be sniffed. Yeah, including data, like passwords — this is why all the cool kids are using http**s** ;)
3. Hostname. Afaik Ubuntu has Avahi installed by default, which implements zero configuration protocol, which shares hostname.
4. OS. It's easy to scan a device with nmap to know what OS it running, by no way it is a hidden info.

Note, that ideally you have to use Firewall *(i.e. UFW)*, otherwise it's also easy to scan your open ports with nmap, and find out what services you have running.

Comment: You saved me from asking on Super User :)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu (or other Linux distros) shares the exact some data other OSes do with the router/AP it is connected to.

Ports is another completely different issue. Ubuntu and the vast majority of distros have them closed by default whereas the mainstream desktop OS has a lot of them open.

Comment: The question would become: what also other OSes share when connecting? (Maybe should ask on stack overflow?)

Comment: You're looking at the issue in a wrong way.  Wireless connections are no different than others in terms of online safety -> What you DO online is what matters. OTOH, a given hotspot is more or less secure - locally - depending mostly on the router itself (what it is capable of and how it has been configured), and not so much on the different OSes connected to it.

Comment: @DavideN Rather ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).